# Executing a transaction using the Safe API

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a simple question: how to execute a transaction as soon as the confirmations have been met using the Safe API? I know there is a possibility to do this using the Core SDK, but I am using the API (Java stack). Moreover, is it possible to automatically execute as soon as all confirmations are done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no endpoint to execute the transaction. Once the transaction has all the necesary signatures you can either use the Core SDK as you mention above or get all this information and send this transaction using Web3 or ethers.

This is an on chain operation so someone has to pay for the gas.

If you have a special need you could create a service of your own, which tracks signed transactions on your safe and using an account which you refill regularly to pay for the gas.